# How to move marker above its surrounding markers in MapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have 30 annotations on the map that are very near to each other. I need to add an action, *e.g.* when I press on a button, specific markers get scaled and appear above all surrendering markers. I did the scaling feature but I didn't manage to make the specific marker move above others. Any help?

This is my code:

```
public func scaleAnnotation(_ annotation: BMAnnotation, selectedScale: CGFloat = 1.5) {
    let selectedAnnotation =  mapView.annotations.last(where: { $0.coordinate == annotation.coordinate })
 
    if let selectedAnnotation = selectedAnnotation, let selectedAnnotationView = mapView.view(for: selectedAnnotation) , selectedAnnotationView !=  lastSelectedAnnotationView {
        resetAnnotationScaling()
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: selectedScale, y: selectedScale)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            selectedAnnotationView.transform = transform
        }
         // move selected annotation view to top 
        // selectedAnnotationView.layer.anchorPointZ = CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        mapView.bringSubviewToFront(selectedAnnotationView)

        lastSelectedAnnotationView = selectedAnnotationView
    } else {
        print(" -  can't find location")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the [`zPriority` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/3547913-zpriority) of `MKAnnotationView`?

Comment: Hi @robmayoff thank you for your comment , i used it but zPriority property is available starting from iOS 14.0 i am targeting iOS 13  so i need a work around